# Which one is better for social networking integration in iOS development?

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, integration, social-networking

I have searched on net for social networking integration in iOS projects (For example: Facebook, Twitter, etc)

I found there are also SDKs available for particulars and some OpenSource projects/frameworks are also available for the same which combines all into one like (ShareKit).

What is the difference in those two? Which one is better to use? Is there any problem to upload an app on AppStore which is using ShareKit framework/code?

Thanks in advance.

Mrunal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ARC in your project ShareKit is a big waste of time. 
Twitter can be added very easily using the Twitter framework and TWTweetComposeViewController. Not sure about any others.

Answer (score 1):

@mrunal check Socialize out: http://www.GetSocialize.com and see what you think.  Full feautre list at http://go.GetSocialize.com/features

DROdio

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking to use Twitter and Facebook, then it is simple enough to just use their API and implement it in your code.

If you are new to development or want to use more (Delicious, Tumblr, Read It Later, Bit.ly, Mail), then I would highly recommend using [ShareKit](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit). It allows for sharing of text, URLs and even images. It takes less than an hour to setup even when using ARC and comes with a sample app to play around with. It is also easy to update when more features are added or the API of one the sites changes.