# Social sites sharing in IOS

Tags: ios, ios5

Need to share IOS application in Facebook,Twitter,Google +.
Is there any common plugin for sharing in IOS.
What about sharekit plugin for sharing?
Please guide me..

Comment: Do you want to share an iOS application itself. Or share content (e.g. photos) from within an iOS application?

Comment: share content from ios application

Comment: share ios application itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to share a content right?
try this: http://getsharekit.com/

Comment: Yes.Please check .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593443/which-one-is-better-for-social-networking-integration-in-ios-development...check first answer bit confuse with that answer

Comment: yes there some known minor issues ins share kit [link](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/issues) but overall it is a good library for sharing into different social networking sites.